# How to handle Stylus/Pen input in QML

Tags: qt, qml, touch, stylus-pen

I am creating a simple drawing application and would like my app handle pen (stylus like Apple Pencil) input. The app is written in Qml/Qt Quick. I know that when using QWidgets you can handle tablet events using `QTabletEvent` ([example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-tablet-example.html)), but how I can handle pen input in QML (using `MouseArea` does not work and I had no luck with `PointHandler` either). Does anyone know if it is possible to handle Pen input in Qt Quick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the example linked by @Albertino80 , I subclassed `QQuickWindow` which inherits `QWindow` and hence is able to receive tablet events (void tabletEvent(QTabletEvent* event). These events can then be used to emit appropriate signals that can be propapated to other QObjects. This method works ok, but it has the problem that event coordinates are not local to the item where they are consumed, instead one has to manually recalculate the position of each event by mapping the coordinates to the custom window.

Answer (score 1):

Try using QML TapHandler: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-taphandler.html

```
acceptedDevices: PointerDevice.Mouse | PointerDevice.Stylus
```

Comment: Isn't `TapHandler` the same as `PointHandler`. I have tried this
       `PointHandler {
            id: handler
            acceptedDevices: PointerDevice.TouchScreen | PointerDevice.Stylus
        }`

Comment: Maybe there is something not working properly. I suggest to study this: https://github.com/dragly/hello-remarkable here I can see a `class TabletWindow : public QQuickWindow` that handles the `tabletEvent` and sends to a child `class PaintedCanvas : public QQuickPaintedItem`

Comment: That's a very useful example thanks. It seems like I need to subclass a custom `QQuickWindow` and from there handle the tablet events.

Comment: It seems like the  Qt developers forgot to implement the handler for tablet events (there is TODO in this [code](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtdeclarative/src/quick/items/qquickwindow.cpp.html#2374))

Comment: 5.15 is releasing soon and will finally have TabletEvents propagating around QML properly. So the Handlers can actually finally restrict to Tablet devices.